# Text alignment not happening in table cells when mobile view is used in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a web application which needs both desktop and mobile view. I am using Angular JS for it. Everything is working fine except the text alignment in tables. I have tried `<td align="left">` but it dint make any difference. 
Here is my code of the table:

```
<tr style="height: 35px; text-align: left" class="{{event.holiday ||event.sunday ? 'vacationBgColor' : 'nonVacationBgColor'}}" data-ng-repeat="event in week.eventsOfPersonByDateList">
<td width="10%">{{ event.dayDate }}</td>
<td colspan="7">
<table style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="day in event.eventDataList" style="height: 35px; text-align: left">
<td width="10%">{{ day.tCode }}</td>
<td width="10%">{{ day.beginTime === '00:00' ? '&nbsp;': day.beginTime }}</td>
<td width="10%">{{ day.endTime === '00:00' ? '&nbsp;' :day.endTime }}</td>
<td width="10%">{{ day.tsCode }}</td>
<td width="12%">{{ day.scUnitCode }}</td>
<td width="10%">{{day.sourceCode }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
```

Am I missing something very basic? Should I add anything else? Please help me.

Comment: can u create jsfiddle so that I can check easily

Comment: @ debin sorry I dint get you.

Comment: put your code in https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: u can try <td align="right"> instead of `text-align` in tr

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o0kfcxdz/ Please check here.

Comment: do u want `td` text in left alignment?

Comment: @debin yes. I tried <td align="right"> but tdid not make any difference

Comment: may b i didnot get u exactly..if u check in chrome then it will show u in left direction.. :/

Comment: The alignment is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed">
```

add this to your code

Comment: or try padding-left:2px